# OpenContainer animation not working in a SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

This is my code:

```
child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 15, right: 15),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              OpenContainer(
                transitionType: ContainerTransitionType.fadeThrough,
                closedBuilder: (BuildContext _, VoidCallback opencontainer) {
                  return GestureDetector(...);
                },
                openBuilder: (BuildContext _, VoidCallback __) {
                  return SizedBox(
                    height: 500,
                    child: Text("Works"),
                  );
                },
              ),
...
```

The **SingleChildScrollView** is also within a container for alignment in the page. **GestureDetector** has an **InkWell** within it which has a **Card**.

I have the animations package installed and working, what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Perks of being a programmer; due to going through a long process of getting widgets to work by putting them within other widgets, I just copied and pasted them into the **closedBuilder**.

The simple solution was to just take the **Card** and place it within the *return* statement of the **closedBuilder**, without its **GestureDetector** and InkWell (of course, both of them have onTaps as well, would make things very wonky).